# Extesnions not installed in Containers in VS code insiders

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have a `.devcontainer` file that pulls a docker image and installs extensions.

However, the extensions are only get installed in VS Code **NOT** VS Code Insiders. I was wondering if anyone can help me with that.

**VS Code Insiders, no extension installed**
[image: VS Code Insiders, no extension installed]

**VS Code, all extensions installed**
[image: VS Code, all extensions installed]

My `.devcontainer` file is the following (I just removed what I am mounting). BTW, I don't use a `dockerfile` in this setup.

```json
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/devcontainer.json or this file's README at:
// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.128.0/containers/docker-existing-dockerfile
{
    "name": "parallel_env",

    // Sets the run context to one level up instead of the .devcontainer folder.
    "context": "..",

    // Update the 'dockerFile' property if you aren't using the standard 'Dockerfile' filename.
    "image": "neuromechanist/emg_processing:v1.0",

    // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": null
    },

    // argumnets to add to docker run
    "runArgs": ["--memory=64g","--shm-size=128g"],

    // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
    "extensions": [
        "ms-vscode.azure-account",
        "ms-kubernetes-tools.vscode-aks-tools",
        "mindaro.mindaro",
        "googlecloudtools.cloudcode",
        "streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker",
        "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker",
        "mindaro-dev.file-downloader",
        "github.vscode-pull-request-github",
        "eamodio.gitlens",
        "ms-kubernetes-tools.vscode-kubernetes-tools",
        "ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare",
        "gimly81.matlab",
        "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
        "ms-python.python",
        "visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode",
        "redhat.vscode-yaml"],

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    "forwardPorts": [8265, 8266, 8267, 8268, 8269],

//    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
//   "workspaceMount": "source=remote-workspace,target=/workspace,type=volume"

    "mounts": [   ]

    // Uncomment the next line to run commands after the container is created - for example installing curl.
    // "postCreateCommand": "apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl",

    // Uncomment when using a ptrace-based debugger like C++, Go, and Rust
    // "runArgs": [ "--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE", "--security-opt", "seccomp=unconfined" ],

    // Uncomment to use the Docker CLI from inside the container. See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/samples/docker-from-docker.
    // "mounts": [ "source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock,type=bind" ],

    // Uncomment to connect as a non-root user. See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
    // "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

Comment: I think we need to see your dockerfile and the files you are copying and where they are being put

Comment: Thanks @Samathingamajig, I added my `.devcontaner`. I don't use a dockerfile. I directly pull the image from `.devcontainer`.

It was the same when I had dockerfile as well though.